# Integrating $\int \frac{\sin x-\cos x}{(\sin x+\cos x)\sqrt{(\sin x \cos x + \sin^2x\cos^2x)}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I came across a question today...

> Integrate $\int \dfrac{\sin x-\cos x}{(\sin x+\cos x)\sqrt{(\sin x \cos x + \sin^2x\cos^2x)}}\,dx$

How to do it? I tried
1. to take **$\sin x \cos x =t$** but no result
2. to convert the thing in the square root into $\sin x +\cos x$ so that I could take $\sin x + \cos x = t$ but then something I got is $\int\frac{-2}{t|t+1|\sqrt{t-1}}\,dt$. Now I don't know how to get past through it.

Comment: take $y = \tan^{-1}(\sqrt{t-1})$.

Comment: If your substitution is correct then define $u:=\sqrt{t-1}$
$$\int\frac{-2}{t(t+1)\sqrt{t-1}}\ dt = -4 \int \frac{1}{(u^2+1)(u^2+2)} du$$
and by partial fractions you get
$$=-4 \int \left(\frac{1}{u^2+1} - \frac{1}{u^2+2} \right) du$$
These are now pretty standard integrals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice,

\begin{align}
& \qquad \int\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{(\sin x+\cos x)\sqrt{\sin x\cos x+\sin^2 x\cos^2x}}\ dx\\
& \quad=\int\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{(\sin x+\cos x)\sqrt{\frac{(\sin x+\cos x)^4-1}{4}}}\ dx\\
&\quad=2\int\frac{(\sin x-\cos x)dx}{(\sin x +\cos x)\sqrt{(\sin x+\cos x)^4-1}}
\end{align}
let $\sin x+\cos x=t\implies (\cos x-\sin x)\ dx=dt$,
$$=-2\int\frac{dt}{t\sqrt{t^4-1}} \qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$
let $t^4-1=u^2\implies 4t^3\ dt=2u\ du$,

\begin{align}
&=-2\int\frac{udu}{2u(u^2+1)}\\
&=-\int\frac{du}{1+u^2}\\
&=-\tan^{-1}(u)+C\\
&=-\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{t^4-1}\right)+C\\
&=-\tan^{-1}\left(2\sqrt{\sin x\cos x+\sin^2x\cos^2 x}\right)+C\\
\end{align}

Comment: ah...the only fault is that the answer in my practice sheet is positive tan inverse...but no problem by my side in catching the concept...thanks...

Comment: are you sure that numerator in the given integral is $\sin x-\cos x$ or it's $\cos x-\sin x$?

Comment: i m pakka wala sure... :p